# Console textgame.exe works on windows 7, not on vista… WHY?

Tags: windows, console, compatibility

Hey so i've made a text game using the pdCurses library and microsoft opperating system tools. Here are my includes and look below for other explination:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h> // or "ctime"
#include <stdio.h> // for 
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <Windows.h> 
#include <conio.h>
#include<curses.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <ctime>

#include <myStopwatch.h> // for keeping times
#include <myMath.h>      // numb_digits() and digit_val();
```

myStopwath/Math.h includes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <tchar.h>
```

So i've tested the game (which includes a folder containing the .exe and pdcurses.dll) on my computer running windows 7 and it works great, however when running it on another computer which has vista or older my game comes up, but immediatly ends due to the loss of all the players lives almost instantaniously.... how could this be?

If you would like to see the full source code, go to this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133402/problems-with-a-console-text-game-im-a-noob)

**Thanks!**

Comment: That link only leads to another stackoverflow-question. I can't find any source-code there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the main game loop, you are not initializing the `coll` variable before passing it to `theScreen.check_collision()`.  If the player is in no danger, then that function does not update this value.  Back in the main loop you don't check the return value from check_collision(), and the program is now making decisions based on whatever uninitialized value was in that variable.  Welcome to the wide world of Undefined Behavior.

It is likely the difference you're seeing on different OS's is due to the way the different heap managers initialize memory pages.  Even if your player survives for a while, after the first collision, that memory location now holds 'X', which is then never cleared, and while the result is still "undefined", on most architectures, this will result in registering a new collision on each iteration, explaining why your "lives" are vanishing so quickly.

Two things you need to do to fix this:

1. All code paths through check_collision must write to the 'buff' out parameter.  The easiest way to do this is initialize it to 0 in the first line of the function.  (Alternatively, if it's intended as an in/out param, then you need to initialize it in the main loop before calling check_collision() )
2. Make your decision based on the return value of check_collision(), rather than the out parameter.  (Or, if that return value really is not important, change the return type of the function to void)

Answer (score 0):

Line 23 in string_lines is missing a comma at the end. Don't think this is your whole issue, but that can't be good either.

You didn't say if you recompiled it separately under each OS (Vista, etc). And if you did recompile, whether same version of compiler was used.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 shipped with Visual C++ 2008 runtime.
Windows Vista shipped Visual C++ 2005 runtime.
XP shipped with Visual C++ 6.0 runtime.

Since you compiled the application in Visual Studio 2010, more than likely it was not compiled to target older operating systems.

Try installing the latest runtimes on the machine you are testing with and if it works after doing that, you know to recompile your project to support older operating systems.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5555 x86
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14632 x64